# RestKit Object Mapping with large number of properties

Tags: objective-c, restkit, rkobjectmapping

I have used `RKObjectMapping` for parsing my JSON response using RestKit.

For ex:.

```
RKObjectMapping *menuItemMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MenuCategoryItem_arr class]];
[menuItemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"item_id",
                                                 @"name",
                                                 @"item_description",
                                                 @"price",
                                                 @"offer_price"]];
```

I have used `[RKObjectManager postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:]`.
This all works fine there's no issue with these mechanisms.

---

My question is what if i have large number of properties in a class? lets say 50 or 60? how would you map these number of properties in a shorter way?
I have an Rest API which may have more than 40 properties? do i have to define all attribute using `addAttributeMappingsFromArray:`? or is there any other way?

Thanks in advance